# CSS ONLY - how to slide out menu on button hover?

Tags: css, hover, onhover

I want the menu to slide out when I hover over a button. Somehow I it only works when I add the hover effect to the menu itself, not to a button. All I could find online was the same (hover effect was attached to the menu that should slide out, not a button). How can I implement that?
jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/codingcodingcoding/tuhug8x8/

html:

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon" style="font-size:40px;z-index:2;"> </span>
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

css:

```
.icon:hover#navigation {
  left: 0;
}

.icon {
  left: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon" style="font-size:40px;z-index:2;"> </span>
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

css:

```
.icon:hover + #navigation {
  left: 0;
}

.icon {
  left: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}
```

Here, I have added just `+` selector olny.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the + or ~ CSS selector if you want to keep your current HTML structure like this :

```css
.icon:hover + #navigation {
  left: 0;
}

.icon {
  left: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon" style="font-size:40px;z-index:2;"> </span>
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can [read more about](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

Comment: @javascript2016 you're welcome ;) don't forget that you can also use `~` the same way, simply replace the + ... and you may mark the answer as accepted too :)

Answer (score 0):

`#navigation` should be a *child element* of the icon container (which in your case is the `span` element) in order to be able to select it on hover. You just have to move the closing `span` tag as shown below.

(I used an image instead of the icon here n the snippet, but in the fiddle, you'll see the icon: https://jsfiddle.net/qLy4g8sL/1/ )

```css
.icon {
  left: 0px;
}

#navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
}
.icon:hover #navigation {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home icon" style="font-size:40px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
<nav id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</span>
```